# How can I format a responsive <figure> containing image and text?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

I am trying to insert a responsive image and text link to a workshop page inside an online article.

It seemed to me that I could fit this within a figure tag (containing the styling for the promo box) to copy and paste it easily into multiple articles.

The image on the left hand side must occupy 10% of the figure width, scaling responsively to the browser window.

The image must not float over the text below.

The text on the right must align to the top of the image and split over two paragraphs, scaling responsively to the remaining space.

The text must not wrap around the image.

There should be margins of 10px around the image and text.

Currently I am using a two cell table, but I cannot seem to make the left hand image cell scale responsively whilst simultaneously scaling the image to fill the cell 100%.

Also the table code seems clunky overlong overkill.

Is there a **quicker and easier way** to execute this? Perhaps using side-by-side divs?

ETA

I am being advised that I should be able to do this simply with divs, float, and display:inline, but I cannot find a way?

Current code (updated as of 16/5/2019 12:00 UST):

```
<figure style="margin:20px 0px 20px 0px;border-top:1px solid #555555;border-bottom:1px solid #555555;padding:10px 20px 5px 20px;">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="30">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 15%;" valign="top"><a href="https://mutiny.asia/Workshops/Data-Driven-Decision-Making" target="_blank"><img src="https://mutiny.asia/Portals/0/EasyGalleryImages/770/PortfolioPro/Thumbs/51data-driven-decision-making.png" style="width: 100%;"></a></td>
   <td style="padding:5px 0 0 10px" valign="top">
   <p>This tutorial is part of our Asia Pacific workshop series covering how effective marketing is empowered by data driven decision making.</p>

   <p>You can <a href="https://mutiny.asia/Workshops/Data-Driven-Decision-Making" target="_blank">find out more about our Data Driven Decision Making Workshops here</a>.</p>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</figure>
```

Comment: Can you follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and include some code with your question?

Comment: Current table code added - this is what I am hoping to replace with something simpler and responsive.

Comment: So you're looking for another way to output the same structure as you have in that code?

Comment: `valign` is obsolete. And the `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Comment: if valign is obsolete, how do I get the text to align at the top? the closing slash on img is a forced error from my DNN editor

Comment: re. The Unknown, the code does not meet requirements because it does not make the img 10% of the figure width, and hence it is not responsive

Answer (score 0):

If you want an object to use all the space of their parent object then you have to set 100% instead of px. However if the image should always just take 10% of the figure then it's 10%. That's assuming that the figure is the parent object of the img

Comment: the figure is not currently the parent object for the img - the table is. If I apply a % width in the table I get a % of the cell, not the figure